# Grails: How to combine findAllBy and findAllByTag

Tags: grails, tags, findall

as I am new to Grails and dynamic languages, I do have some 'hopefully simple' question.

I installed the taggable plugin which works fine. There is an array coming in with tags. I collect for every tag the set of data with findAllByTag. After that I randomise it and pick one entry. Works great. Now I decided not to take all objects from the DB. I only need all with a certain creteria(DB column customerID). This would look like this:

```
def customerSet = Customer.findAllBycustomerID(params.customerID)
```

I got both querys working, but can not combine as I want. I tried something like

```
def hits = customerSet.findAllByTag(tag)
```

But then I get a

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.findAllByTag() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [mac]

I guess I can not do a findAllByTag on a list like that.

Or do I have to do it somehow like this:

```
def customerSet = Customer.findAllBycustomerID(params.customerID.findAllByTag(tag)) ???
```

thanks,
klaas

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works with taggable but you can use a dynamic finder with two properties e.g. .findAllByCustomerIdAndTag(customerId,tag)

If that doesn't work, you can use a criteria e.g.

```
Customer.createCriteria().list{
    eq('customerId',someCustomerId)
    tags{
        eq('name',someTag')
    }
}
```